# Azure AD Create guest user with password

Tags: azure-active-directory

In Azure Active Directory, how can I create a guest user who is prompted for a password on every sign-in and prompted to change his password on the first sign-in?

After inviting a guest user in the portal (Active Directory -> Add User -> Invite User (by email)) and accepting the invitation, the user cannot change his password.

Sign-in always prompts for email OTP, attempts to change the password as the user fail.

Answer (score 1):

Members can be changed to guests after creation.

1. Create a new User (Member)
2. Edit the user to add the email address
3. Edit the user to change the user type to Guest

Such a user will be prompted to change his password on the first sign-in and is prompted for the password on further sign-ins.